# Sprite movement speed is not constant in all device - Andengine

Tags: android, andengine

I'm creating an android game and using AndEngine. Background Sprite movement speed is not same in different devices,its varying. I'm using the below code to move bgSprite. How to maintain constant speed of the game for different devices.?

```
 bgSprite1.setPosition(bgSprite1.getX() - 10, bgSprite1.getY());
```

Comment: Good luck on this... I think you will have your work cut out for you as different devices have different processor speeds and rendering capabilities

Comment: Register a TimerHandler() for your update handler, and put your position update code within it. I guess your current code is changing position per frame, so the speed vary from device to device.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Class extending Sprite, for example i made this for me (shouldDie it's a var that i use to know when to destroy the sprite(in this case when it's out of the screen)):

```
public class BackgroundMovingLine extends Sprite {

public boolean shouldDie;
private int speed;

BackgroundMovingLine(final int pX,final int pY, final ITextureRegion pTextureRegion, final VertexBufferObjectManager pVertexBufferObjectManager)
{
    super(pX,pY,pTextureRegion,pVertexBufferObjectManager);
    shouldDie=false;

    speed=(new Random()).nextInt(150)+250;
}
@Override
protected void onManagedUpdate(final float pSecondsElapsed) { 

    float h=this.getY();

    h=(h+(speed*pSecondsElapsed));

    if(h>800)
    {
        shouldDie=true;
    }

    this.setY(h);

}
}
```

Speed it's the speed of the moving sprite.
I made it random but you can set it to what you want.